# Problems in compiling @ngrx/core @ngrx/store in Angular

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm trying to build project in angular and recently I installed ngrx in my project after that I am getting below error:

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ng-complete-guide-update",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "^11.0.5",
    "@ngrx/store": "^13.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.9",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Error:

```
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/feature_creator_models.d.ts:4:23 - error TS1005: ']' expected.

4     [K in FeatureName as `select${Capitalize<K>}State`]: MemoizedSelector<AppState, FeatureState>;
                        ~~
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/feature_creator_models.d.ts:4:48 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

4     [K in FeatureName as `select${Capitalize<K>}State`]: MemoizedSelector<AppState, FeatureState>;
                                                 ~
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/feature_creator_models.d.ts:7:43 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

7     [K in keyof FeatureState & string as `select${Capitalize<K>}`]: MemoizedSelector<AppState, FeatureState[K]>;
                                            ~~~~~~~
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/feature_creator_models.d.ts:7:50 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

7     [K in keyof FeatureState & string as `select${Capitalize<K>}`]: MemoizedSelector<AppState, FeatureState[K]>;
                                                   ~
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/feature_creator_models.d.ts:7:64 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

7     [K in keyof FeatureState & string as `select${Capitalize<K>}`]: MemoizedSelector<AppState, FeatureState[K]>;
                                                                 ~
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/feature_creator_models.d.ts:9:1 - error TS1160: Unterminated template literal.

9
```

Comment: Try installing ngrx 11 since you are using angular 11. You have ngrx 13 installed at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular and NgRx versions aren't compatible.
NgRx 13 uses TypeScript features that aren't available on TS v4.0.x

You'll have to downgrade NgRx to v11, or Angular to v13 (to keep the versions compatible).

Comment: Hello Sir as per your instruction I Upgrated ngRX with using ng update @ngrx/store@11 command. now I am facing error like  **Cannot read property 'config' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null** can yu please help me